# Rest api via spring

Tags: java, mysql, rest, spring-mvc

I have to get all data from `MySQL` in a table using condition `select` query where fields is isdeleted=0, location=1. How could I implement this in repository and access manager.

```
public interface FoodCourtRepository  extends JpaRepository<FoodCourtEntity, Long> {
    List<FoodcaseEntity> findByIsdeleted(Boolean isDeleted);
}
```

In access manager

```
public List<FoodcaseDO> getAllFoodCourt() {
    List<FoodcaseEntity> foodCaseList = foodcourtRepository.findByIsdeleted(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA provides @Query to write custom query. You can define another interface called FoodCourtRepositoryCustom and write custom query as below:

```
public interface FoodCourtRepositoryCustom {
 @Query("SELECT fe FROM FoodcaseEntity fe WHERE fe.isdeleted=?1 AND fe.location=?2 ")
 List<FoodcaseEntity> findByIsdeletedAndLocation(Boolean isDeleted, Integer location);
}
```

Then extends this interface in your repository inteface as below:

```
public interface FoodCourtRepository  extends JpaRepository<FoodCourtEntity, Long>, FoodCourtRepositoryCustom{
List<FoodcaseEntity> findByIsdeleted(Boolean isDeleted);
}
```

Now method is available in your access manager.

```
public List<FoodcaseDO> getAllFoodCourt() {
List<FoodcaseEntity> foodCaseList = foodcourtRepository.findByIsdeleted(false);
List<FoodcaseEntity> foodCaseList = foodcourtRepository.findByIsdeletedAndLocation(false, 1);
}
```

Comment: sir this method showing json data but when i am changing location =2 in url same data is shown like for location=1 localhost:8080/court/court/list?location=1 now if i change location=2 same data comes for location =1 localhost:8080/court/court/list?location=2,3,4,5

Comment: can you post sample data in comment for FoocaseEntity table so i can check and help you.

Comment: String name;String address;String description; Boolean isdeleted;int location; now if isdeleted =0,and location =1 the list must show data in json but when i check in url -----localhost:8080/court/court/list?location=1.it show json data but when i change location=2 it show same data

Comment: @Column(name = "name", length = 45, nullable = false)private Stringname;@Column(name = "address", length = 45, nullable = false)
private String address;@Column(name = "description", length = 100, nullable = true)private String description;@Column(name = "IS_DELETED", length = 3, nullable = false)private Boolean isdeleted;@Column(name = "location",length = 15, nullable = false)
 private int location;

Comment: i think you are not changing hard coded value passed as location parameter.

Comment: change it as `public List<FoodCourtEntity> getAllFoodCourt(int location) {
  return foodCourtRepository.findByIsdeletedAndLocation(false, location);
 }`

Comment: and pass this parameter from controller as `@ResponseBody
 @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public List<FoodCourtEntity> courtList(@RequestParam Integer location){
  return foodCourtService.getAllFoodCourt(location);
 }`

Comment: what to do with implementation manager   public class FoodCourtManagerImpl {
 @Autowired
 private FoodCourtAccessManager foodCourtAccessManager;
 
public List<FoodCourtDO> foodcourts(){
  
  List<FoodCourtDO> foodCourtDOList = 
    foodCourtAccessManager.getAllFoodCourt(deliverylocation);

Comment: I can see there are multiple layer in your app. You have to decide responsibility of layers. here only thing i can see is you are missing location passing based on url parameter. Read more on multi-tier application in spring.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply now code is working fine thanks a lot sir

Answer (score 4):

You need to add another condition as well, for location, e.g.:

```
public List<FoodcaseEntity> findByIsdeletedAndLocation(boolean deleted, int location);
```

And call it with `false` and `1` as arguments, e.g.:

```
List<FoodcaseEntity> foodCaseList = foodcourtRepository.findByIsdeletedAndLocation(false, 1);
```

This should give you the required result.

**Updte**

If you want to fetch the data for multiple locations then you need to write a method that supports `IN`, e.g.:

```
public List<FoodcaseEntity> findByIsdeletedAndLocationIn(boolean deleted, List<Integer> location);
```

And then call it like this:

```
List<FoodcaseEntity> foodCaseList = foodcourtRepository.findByIsdeletedAndLocation(false, Arrays.asList(2,3,4,5));
```

Comment: finding error in repository ----(Invalid derived query! No property anddeliveryLocation found for type Boolean! Traversed path: FoodCourtEntity.isdeleted.)

Comment: sir this method showing json data but when i am changing location =2 in url same data is shown like for location=1                                                       http://localhost:8080/court/court/list?location=1                                      now if i change location=2 same data comes for location =1                                   http://localhost:8080/court/court/list?location=2,3,4,5

Comment: @bkumar updated the answer. Basically, you need to write another method that supports `IN` query to get the data for multiple locations.

Answer (score 0):

In a repository class add,

```
List<FoodcaseEntity> foodCaseList = foodcourtRepository.findByIsdeletedAndLocation(boolean isSelected,int location);
```

then u can send selected and location values.it will return list of values based on condition.